# Question on probability and coin toss.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A coin is tossed in an experiment with Akshay noting the result. He stops the experiment when notes a sequence of exactly 3 tails.what is the probability that the experiment ends with 7 tosses.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- The fourth, fifth, sixth, and seventh tosses must be HTTT; why? What is the probability of this?
- What is the only string of three results that the first three tosses *cannot* have? What is the probability that they don’t have this one bad string?
- How must you combine the probabilities from the preceding points in order to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

To end with exactly seven tosses the last four tosses must have been `HTTT`, and the first three tosses *cannot* have been `TTT`.   What is the probability of this?